# Не могу подключить kaki для hot reload kivy приложения. Ошибка Message: 'Reloader: Error when building app' Arguments: ()

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Есть подобное `kivy` приложение
https://pastebin.com/5uZdWXR4 - `main.py`(лежит в папке on-build)
https://pastebin.com/RkxTdPnG - `Menu.kv`(лежит в папке on-build)

Пытаюсь используя `kaki` написать скрипт для изменения приложения во время работы

https://pastebin.com/dm2e4cvN - `debug.py`(лежит в папке перед on-build)

Получаю 2 ошибки

1. `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Menu.kv'`
   Хотя указываю в `KV_FILES` путь к файлу
2. [https://pastebin.com/QbTWeJ08\](https://pastebin.com/QbTWeJ08%5C)
   При использовании DEBUG=1 python debug.py
   И попытке изменить `Menu.kv` Который я перенес в папку к `debug.py`

   python 3.10
   kivy 2.1.0
   kivymd 1.1.1
   kaki 0.1.9.dev0

Answer (score 0):

куда указывает os.getcwd? Попробуйте добавить вывод функции до `return Factory.EljurApp()`:

```
def build_app(self):
    print("Current path:", os.getcwd())
    return Factory.EljurApp()
```

скорее всего при запуске передаётся другой путь, отличный от ожидаемого.
У себя замечал такое поведение, когда путь возвращаемый os.getcwd() был на один уровень выше и пришёл к выводу, что это могло быть из-за настроек проекта, но это только догадки.